# Data loss on Azure Container Instance with mounted volume

Tags: sql-server, azure, docker, containers, docker-volume

I just created a container instance on azure with an sql server docker image and a mounted file sharing storage as a volume. The fact is that the container got stucked, so I restarted it.

After restart, all data was gone. When I restart a docker container locally, data keep existing because of volumes so I cannot understand the behaviour on azure.

Any clue about this?

Here is the cli command I run to create the container

```
az container create --resource-group myresource-rg \
--name project-test-db \
--image mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest \
--location westus2 \
--ports 1433 \
--memory 5  \
--environment-variables SA_PASSWORD=Password ACCEPT_EULA=Y \ 
--ip-address public \
--azure-file-volume-account-name projectteststorageacc \ 
--azure-file-volume-account-key \MyKey \ 
--azure-file-volume-share-name project-test-file-share \ 
--azure-file-volume-mount-path /databases
```

Comment: What do you mean by "container got stucked" ? Can you elaborate or share more error logs if any for this event ?

Comment: I meant that the container crashed. I currently have no log errors about it

Comment: was my answer helpful ?

Comment: I did not try it yet. I changed the database to a DTU serverless azure SQL database that was cheaper than a container for my testing purposes. However I will try your solution this weekend and let you know if this works. Thank you Very much

Comment: Did you get a chance to try my approach

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MT yes, but the problem is still there. Maybe i'm doing something wrong with binding volumes

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your command as below

Use `" "`  for around `ACCEPT_EULA=Y`  and  `key-value` pair as below. And replace `SA_PASSWORD` with `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD`

```
--environment-variables "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Password" "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" \
```

Required setting for the SQL Server image, a strong password that is at least 8 characters and meets the [SQL Server password requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/password-policy?view=sql-server-ver15). Given if you have set appropriate **strong** password and storage key already, the below commands works just fine for me. If the password doesn't meet SQL standards this container fails (restart loop).

```
PS /home/karthik> $Password = "MyStrongPassword"
PS /home/karthik> $key = "FO/R6WkZELhMzX02wi9KahtLtKppoSIJg/EcJLEnZajRm2uxXs0sb/APaCk1eRsNW31yijSjS1hFm5Rd4rdTew=="

az container create --resource-group Myrg \
--name project-test-db \
--image mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest \
--location westus2 \
--ports 1433 \
--memory 5  \
--environment-variables "SA_PASSWORD=$Password" "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" \ 
--ip-address public \
--azure-file-volume-account-name kteststoragee \ 
--azure-file-volume-account-key $key \ 
--azure-file-volume-share-name ktestfs2 \ 
--azure-file-volume-mount-path /databases
```

[image]

[image]

When you have a misbehaving container in Azure Container Instances, start by viewing its logs with [az container logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container#az_container_logs), and stream its standard out and standard error with [az container attach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container#az_container_attach).

The [az container attach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container#az_container_attach) command provides diagnostic information during container startup. Once the container has started, it streams STDOUT and STDERR to your local console.

Refer: [Quickstart: Run SQL Server container images with Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-bash) and [Docker run command fails with Accept-Eula Agreement error #199](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/199)